# Background img with filterand nav - CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I have the next question:
I have a div with  background img, I added a filter brightness, but that also affected what I have next to that image:
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

html:

```
<header>
   <div id="logo-page">
        <div id="top-bar">
            <nav>
                <a href="#" class="menu">home</a>
                <a href="#work" class="menu">work</a>
                <a href="#projects" class="menu">projects</a>
                <a href="#gallery" class="menu">gallery</a>
                <a href="#papers" class="menu">papers</a>
                <a href="#" class="menu">contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Logo -->
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#logo-page{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
background-image: url("../img/logo.jpg");
width: auto;
height: 100vh;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
filter:brightness(0.5);
```

}

the idea is that the nav or what you add inside of  is not affected by the filter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are applying the brightness filter to the whole "logo-page" container, which also contains the navbar. If you want to apply the filter to only the background image, you have to create another container for the image and apply the filter there.
Note that we set the **z-index** value in the new image container to -1, so it displays behind the navbar, and **position: fixed** for both containers.

HTML:

```
<header>
   <div id="logo-page">
        <div id="top-bar">
            <nav>
                <a href="#" class="menu">home</a>
                <a href="#work" class="menu">work</a>
                <a href="#projects" class="menu">projects</a>
                <a href="#gallery" class="menu">gallery</a>
                <a href="#papers" class="menu">papers</a>
                <a href="#" class="menu">contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="background-image"></div>
    </div><!-- Logo -->
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#logo-page{
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

#top-bar {
  position: fixed;
}

#background-image {
  background-image: url("../img/logo.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  filter:brightness(0.5);

  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;

  z-index: -1;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x53r8nmk/3/